# Combine the multiple files with one header

Tags: r

I have five text files that are produced by an `R` program, (each of them having header) that are to be combined into a single file. I have combined them using `rbind` and my problem is when I combine them, the resultant output has headers attached at end of each file for example,
if the headers are supposed

```
Combine Resultant file
A  B  C  D
1  3  5  7    ------------> Text file1
6  9  0  3
A  B  C  D
1  3  6  7    ------------> Text file 2
5  7  8  3
and so on....
```

instead of that I want the output file to have only one header at line 1
so the file should look like:

```
Combine Resultant file
A  B  C  D
1  3  5  7    ------------> Text file1
6  9  0  3
1  3  6  7    ------------> Text file 2
5  7  8  3
and so on....
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that?
The code I have is:

```
S1 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_1_200.txt",sep=";",header= TRUE);
S2 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_201_400.txt", sep=";",header= TRUE);
S3 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_401_600_b.txt", sep=";",header= TRUE);
S4 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_601_800.txt", sep=";",header= TRUE);
S5 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_901_1000.txt",sep=";",header= TRUE);
S6 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/simulations_801_900.txt",sep=";",header= TRUE);
options(max.print=28.5E6);
S7 <- rbind(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6)
write.table(S7, file="C:/Simulation_Results/simulation_1_1000.txt", sep=";", 
            row.names=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks correct to me. Maybe the error is in the txt files generated by your other program. Could we see `head(S1)` and `tail(S1)`, please? Also, it's helpful to format the code in your question (highlight the code sections and push the code button -- the one with 1010 on it).

Comment: Can we see see head and tail of S1? Is part of the problem commas and decimals? Like Dwin pointed out, your R code that write the txt files is probably misforming the headers.

Comment: Do you have the code that generates the files? If so, I would just save the tables to individual variables x1 <- as.data.frame(table1) for example. And then rbind()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an improper import. You should provide an example data. Anyway, instead of using `read.table("some.file", header=TRUE, sep=";")`, give `read.csv2` a try, since it has `header=TRUE` and `sep=";"` as default arguments.

And instead `rbind`, why don't you use `merge`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; There is a problem with your input data not matching your read function and you are reading in data with the wrong sep argument. I think you need to skip one line to get down to the point where the headers are. Try this:

```
S1 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_1_200.txt", header= TRUE, skip=1)
S2 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_201_400.txt",  skip=1, header= TRUE)
S3 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_401_600_b.txt", skip=1 , header= TRUE)
S4 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_601_800.txt", skip=1, header= TRUE)
S5 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/sim_901_1000.txt", skip=1 , header= TRUE)
S6 <- read.table("C:/Simulation_Results/simulations_801_900.txt", skip=1, header= TRUE)
```

Then proceed as before. The sep=";" was preventing the white-space separation from being recognized and there was something in the leading line that was causing your headers not to be converted to column names.

Answer (score 0):

following up on DWin: how about

```
startvals <- c(1,201,401,601,801,901)
endvals   <- c(startvals[-1]-1,1000)
fns <- paste("C:/Simulation_Results/",startvals,"_",endvals,".txt",sep="")
## I'm assuming for the moment that your S6 file is *not* named differently from the others
S <- lapply(fns, read.csv2, skip=1)
S_comb <- do.call(rbind,S)
```

if you had your simulation files named in a particular way so that you could identify them all with list.files(pattern="[some regular expression]") then you could start that way ...