# Combining tab delim files into a single file using R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, read.table

I have several txt files with 3 columns in each files like this:
file 1:

```
ProbeID X_Signal_intensity X_P-Value   
xxx         2.34          .89
xxx         6.45          .04 
xxx         1.09          .91  
xxx         5.87          .70
.            .            . 
.            .            .
.            .            .
```

file 2:

```
ProbeID Y_Signal_intensity Y_P-Value   
xxx         1.4             .92
xxx         2.55            .14 
xxx         4.19            .16  
xxx         3.47            .80
.            .               . 
.            .               .
.            .               .
```

file 3:

```
ProbeID Z_Signal_intensity Z_P-Value   
xxx         9.40             .82
xxx         1.55            .04 
xxx         3.19            .56  
xxx         2.47            .90
.            .               . 
.            .               .
.            .               .
```

In all the above files the values of ProbeID column are identical but not the other columns.Now I want to combine the all the above files using a *for-loop* into a single file like this:

```
ProbeID X_intensity X_P-Value   Y_intensity Y_P-Value   Z_intensity Z_P-Value     
xxx      2.34          .89       1.4             .92     9.40            .82
xxx      6.45          .04       2.55            .14     1.55            .04
xxx      1.09          .91       4.19            .16     3.19            .56
xxx      5.87          .70       3.47            .80     2.47            .90
```

Please do help me.

Comment: See related questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764292/loading-many-files-at-once , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234179/combine-the-multiple-files-with-one-header , ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to read the files into data.frames

see `help(read.delim)` for reading modes.

After you have your three data.frames you can use

```
total <- merge(dataframeA,dataframeB,by="ProbeID")
```

look here http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html for documentation.

Comment: Would be fun if you also demonstrated that this actually works (see Joris' answer).

Answer (score 4):

Read in the files as given by Richie Cotton, but make sure you add the appropriate extra arguments in the apply call. For one, `header=TRUE` should probably be added.

```
file.names <- c("file X.txt", "file Y.txt", "file Z.txt")
file.list <- lapply(file.names, read.table, header=TRUE)
```

Then you'll probably need a `merge_recurse` from the `reshape package` :

```
require(reshape)
mynewframe <- merge_recurse(file.list,all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE,by="ProbeID")
```

This will work for any given number of dataframes, provided it's not a billion of them. For more information on the arguments used, see the help page of `?merge`.

CORRECTION : in merge_recurse, you have to use `all.x` and `all.y` as shown in the correction above. You can't just use the shortcut `all` or you'll get errors.

Small demonstration :

```
X2 <- data.frame(ProbeID=(2:4),Z2=4:6)
X1 <- data.frame(ProbeID=1:3,Z1=1:3)
X3 <- data.frame(ProbeID=1:3,Z3=7:9)
file.list <- list(X1,X2,X3)
mynewframe <- merge_recurse(file.list,all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE,by="ProbeID")
> mynewframe
  ProbeID Z1 Z2 Z3
1       1  1 NA  7
2       2  2  4  8
3       3  3  5  9
4       4 NA  6 NA
```

Comment: Note that there is a bug in merge_recurse that prevents it from using the additional arguments you are passing. In fact, merge_recurse(file.list) will produce exactly the same output. The bug affects any merge of three or more data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Read in your files

```
filenames <- c("file X.txt", "file Y.txt", "file Z.txt")
data_list <- lapply(filenames, read.table)
```

Combine them into one big data frame

<del>all_data <- do.call(cbind, data_list)</del>

<del>all_data <- do.call(merge, data_list, by = "ProbeID")</del>

This gives a good lesson to "always concentrate when providing an answer".  `cbind` isn't smart enough to do ID matching, and `merge` isn't smart enough to handle more than two data frames.  Take a look at Joris's answer and use `merge_recurse` instead.  Or forget what you thought you wanted and use my other answer below.

---

Actually, a better idea, rather than having many columns would be to have just 4 columns: ProbeID, Signal_intensity, P_value and Source_file.

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- c("ProbeID", "Signal_intensity", "P_value")
  x
})

all_data <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
all_data$Source_file <- rep(filenames, times = sapply(data_list, nrow))
```

Comment: I deleted the comments for cleanup (SO starts complaining lately about extended comments). Feel free to do so too.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to throw another approach into the mix which uses `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), file.list)
```