# How to score a data.frame based on another data.frame?

Tags: r

I'm looking for help on how to append scores to a new data set of the same data based on already discovered patterns from a training data set. Example of what I am looking to do (take from another one of my posts):

Here is a sample data set which outputs the means of some fake online shopper data.

```
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)    

set.seed(123)
dat = data.frame(email=sample(c("yahoo", "gmail"), 10000, replace=T),
                 browser=sample(c("mozilla", "ie"), 10000, replace=T),
                 country=sample(c("usa", "canada"), 10000, replace=T),
                 money=runif(10000))  
dat.withmean <- dat %>%
  group_by(email, browser, country) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(money))

# email browser country      mean
# 1 gmail      ie  canada 0.5172424
# 2 gmail      ie     usa 0.4921908
# 3 gmail mozilla  canada 0.4934892
# 4 gmail mozilla     usa 0.4993923
# 5 yahoo      ie  canada 0.5013214
# 6 yahoo      ie     usa 0.5098280
# 7 yahoo mozilla  canada 0.4985357
# 8 yahoo mozilla     usa 0.4919743
```

Now, let's say we have a new data set that looks like this:

```
newdat = data.frame(email=sample(c("yahoo", "gmail"), 10000, replace=T),
                 browser=sample(c("mozilla", "ie"), 10000, replace=T),
                 country=sample(c("usa", "canada"), 10000, replace=T)) 

head(newdat, n=10)

#   email browser country
#1  gmail      ie     usa
#2  gmail      ie     usa
#3  gmail mozilla  canada
#4  yahoo mozilla  canada
#5  gmail      ie  canada
#6  yahoo mozilla  canada
#7  yahoo mozilla  canada
#8  gmail      ie     usa
#9  yahoo mozilla  canada
#10 gmail mozilla  canada
#... 10,000 rows...
```

How can I loop through newdat and check if any combination of columns from newdat matches any rows from dat and then if it does do something like append the value from the "mean" column in dat?

Comment: Look at `%in%`, `match`

Comment: @infominer Thanks that helps me to start looking in the right direction. Still wondering if there is some "tried and true" simple method out there that someone uses (like a function)

Comment: also look at `?merge` and maybe if you put some sample data from both data.frames and show what you tried we could help, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @infominer merge may be what I want, but can you merge based on 3 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
dat.withmean <- dat %>%
               group_by(email, browser, country) %>%
               summarize(mean = mean(money))
```

Now we use merge, this will "append" or add a column called mean for every combination

```
newdat.withmean <- merge(newdat,dat.withmean) #by default, data.frames are merged on the columns they both have.
```

read `?merge` for more details

Comment: Awesome! Works great. I noticed that it also sorts dat.withmean after the merge. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Merge is not restricted to number of columns, it is restricted to two data.frames though. If you need to merge multiple data.frames look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22332076/2747709

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the temporary variable:

```
result <-     
  dat %>%
  group_by(email, browser, country) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(money)) %>%
  merge(newdat)
```

And you might want to use dplyr's *join family of functions for speeed.